# Problems reading chrome response data

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a popup.js file in popup.html who send request to background.js, background.js get a cookie and if cookie exists it send a response to popup.js.

But when i try to open the popup i receive this errors

> 1 - error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
>
> 2 - Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.

**The Code**

**Background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => {

if (msg.topic === 'data') {
 chrome.cookies.get({ url: 'https://domain', name: 'name' },
function (cookie) {
    if (cookie) {
    sendResponse({data: "yes"});    
          
  } else { sendResponse({data: "no"});  }
     return true;
  
  
}
 )};
  
});
```

**Popup.js**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
topic: 'data'},
function(response) {
  if (response.data == "yes")
  document.write = 'COOKIE YES'
  
   else if (response.data == "no")
  document.write = 'COOKIE NO'
});
```

Thanks to anyone who reply

Comment: `return true;` should return from the onMessage listener, not from chrome.cookies.get callback. Put it **between** the two `)};` at the end.

Answer (score -1):

`"Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received."` is related to a browser extension you have installed, and not the code you are using. Safe to ignore this I believe.

Use `console.log(response)` to see if you are receiving what you think you are receiving.